# Trying to get Hash Maps to Work With JComboBox

Tags: java, hashmap, jcombobox

Im trying to get a hash map to display back how many trainers are being used with people being added to how many are being trained could anyone help me i have the jcombox i just cant get it to work with the hash map it dosnet do anything.

```
 {
           String [] carSales = {"Mick", "Jeff", "Ian", "Andrew", "David" };
           JComboBox<String> trainerList = new JComboBox<String>(carSales);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,trainerList );
        Map<String, Integer> vehicles = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        // Add some vehicles.
        trainerList.put("Mick",4 );
        trainerList.put("Mercedes", 3);
        trainerList.put("Audi", 4);
        trainerList.put("Ford", 10);

        System.out.println("Total vehicles: " + vehicles.size());

        // Iterate over all vehicles, using the keySet method.
        for(String key: trainerList.keySet())
            System.out.println(key + " - " + vehicles.get(key));
        System.out.println();

        String searchKey = "Audi";
        if(vehicles.containsKey(searchKey))
            System.out.println("Found total " + vehicles.get(searchKey) + " "
                    + searchKey + " cars!\n");

        // Clear all values.
        vehicles.clear();

        // Equals to zero.
        System.out.println("After c`enter code here`lear operation, size: " + vehicles.size());
           }
```

Comment: Where are you adding anything to the map? Your map is empty!

Comment: trainerList that line theres 4 things in the map did you read the code?

Comment: Oh I am sorry! I never knew you consider JComboBox as Map. So what about the variable 'vehicles'? What do you refer vehicles as?